# How do I get the CID from my HTC Flyer when it does not boot anymore?

Tags: htc-flyer

My flyer does not boot anymore (due to unsuccessful Honeycomb update try) and I want to reset it to Gingerbread using RUU_Flyer_HTC_WWE_2.23.405.3_R_Radio_20.3504.30.089BU_3809.07.04.06_M_release_204108_signed.exe. But just executing the RUU installer does not work. I need a Goldcard. To make the Goldcard I need the CID of my device.

Usually you extract the CID by this method:

http://android.modaco.com/topic/305672-creating-a-goldcard/

Unfortunately the command gives me the following output:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools>adb shell cat /sys/class/mmc_host/mmc1/mmc1:*/cid error: device not found

My HTC Flyer is connected via USB. HTC Sync is currently not installed. It is RELOCKED and S-OFF.

What can I do?